# Is there a way to compose potentially failing operations in Go?

Tags: go, error-handling, either

Most go code I read contains frequent occurrences of the following pattern:

```
result1, err := failingOp1()
if err != nil {
    return err
}
dependingResult, err := failingOp2(result1)
if err != nil {
    return err
}
// do stuff with dependingResult
```

In functional programming we have the `Either` monad and its cousins (e.g. Scala's `Try`) that allow us to compose failing operations without constantly repeating ourselves.

Is there a go equivalent that helps decluttering the code?

Comment: I would recommend taking a look at https://blog.golang.org/errors-are-values

Comment: Just my two cents. Something I've found regarding immediately handling errors, is how it makes the main flow of the code easier to follow. If everything goes right, most functions simply flow top-to-bottom. We expect them to go right, so reading the expected flow is easy. The concepts of "indent errors, not code" and removing elses further eases the reading of functions. Most of the important stuff is indented only once or twice, so you get a nice left-flushed column to read. Also, there's no curly bracket hell at the end of the function. https://github.com/golang/go/wiki/CodeReviewComments

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Reading up a bit further, in particular [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18772282/2020801), it seems idiomatic go prefers handling errors at the call-site rather than propagating the potential error upwards (which the monadic approach favours).

Following this line of thinking:

```
func wrapFailingOp1() ResultType {
  result1, err := failingOp1()
  if err != nil {
    return defaultRTOrPanic()
  }
  return result1
}

func wrapFailingOp2(result1 ResultType) DependingResultType {
    dependingResult, err := failingOp2(result1)
    if err != nil {
        return defaultDRTOrPanic()
    }
    return dependingResult
}

x := wrapFailingOp1()
y := wrapFailingOp2(x)
```